# get all documents with a particular field, doctrine_mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

Please if `findOneBy(array('user_id' => 1));` produces one row (first document with user_id of 1) in doctrine_mongodb, how do I get all rows having a user_id of 1? `findBy(array('user_id' => $userId));` produces empty coily brackets. user_id is different from my id field.

I have asked a similar question on this forum but got no answer yet.

Thanks

---

Hi I have edited the previous question. Below you would find part of my table definition and controller. Hope it makes my question clear:

```
    /**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */

class scripts
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
public $name;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
public $description;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int
 */
public $index;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int
 */
public $user_id;
```

And My Controller:

```
use My\MpBundle\Document\Scripts;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;//Write the html inside controller
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Types\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class UserjsonController extends Controller
{

public function showuserjsonAction($userId)
   {
$script = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager') ->getRepository('MyMpBundle:Scripts') 
->findBy(array('user_id' => $userId));
```

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to fetch? What's the relation between this data and the user_id? Can you provide the detail of your mapping / definition of the objects you are trying to manipulate?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch all documents or rows from my mongodb database having a user_id of 1. The value of userId is from my routing url: pattern:  platform/designing/users/{userId}/showuserjson

Comment: My problem is I get empty curly brackets when I pass a variable ($userId) but it works perfectly if I pass a number directly (e.g. 3)

Comment: @Kingsley: Please find the document you're expecting using the `mongo` shell, so we can see exactly what it looks like in MongoDB (before ODM does any mapping). Additionally, `var_dump()` the `$userId` argument being passed to your controller method.